# Joomla Phoca gallery issue

Tags: joomla

I've installed **Phoca gallery plugin** in my **Joomla 3.2** site. After installing the pluign,I'm getting some errors.([Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fQFAc.jpg))

Errors are mentioned below,

```
Strict Standards: Declaration of PhocaGalleryCpController::display() should be
compatible with JControllerLegacy::display($cachable = false, $urlparams = Array) in
C:\xampp\htdocs\Joomla\administrator\components\com_phocagallery\controller.php 
on line 55


Strict Standards: Non-static method PhocaGalleryUtils::setVars() should not be
called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in 
C:\xampp\htdocs\Joomla\administrator\components\com_phocagallery\views\
phocagallerycp\view.html.php on line 19


Strict Standards: Non-static method PhocaGalleryRenderInfo::getPhocaVersion() 
should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in 
C:\xampp\htdocs\Joomla\administrator\components\com_phocagallery\views\
phocagallerycp\view.html.php on line 38
```

Comment: make sure Phoca gallery plugin is compatible with Joomla3.2

Answer (score 1):

update to Phoca Gallery 4.1.0, this version was overwritten to prevent from Strict Standards warnings:

http://www.phoca.cz/news/770-phoca-gallery-4-1-0-released

If you are running some obsolete version, on Joomla! production site (Phoca Gallery is a Joomla! component), disable the Strict Standards in Joomla! configuration, set Error Reporting parameter to: None.

See: http://www.phoca.cz/documents/50-phoca/625-strict-standards-non-static-method for more information about Strict Standards.

Jan

Answer (score 0):

These are not properly Errors, but notices that the plugins do not conform to the (current) PHP standards. For future compatibility and maintenance it is important to solve them, but they are in no way a problem now: consider them as notices, not even warnings.

They are shown because you have a development setting on your server's PHP configuration file php.ini, most likely:

```
error_reporting = E_ALL | E_STRICT
```

or you set Joomla! error reporting in development mode from the Global Configuration.

You should set the error_reporting to something less verbose in a production environment, and  let the developers know about it, they should fix it quickly and effortlessly.

Comment: I had tested with error_reporting = E_ALL | E_STRICT already, but still the error continues.

Comment: No the point is you need to use E_ALL or even better E_WARNING for production. E_STRICT is responsible for the notices you see.